# Record OpenAI gym Video with Monitor

Tags: python, openai-gym

I want to record a video of my rollouts of OpenAIs gym. I use the Monitor class, but other solutions are also appreciated. This is a minimal example I created, that runs without exceptions or warnings:

```
import gym
from gym.wrappers import Monitor
env = Monitor(gym.make('CartPole-v0'), './video', force=True)
state = env.reset()
done = False
while not done:
    action = env.action_space.sample()
    state_next, reward, done, info = env.step(action)
env.close()
```

This saves a video and some metadata to the `'./video'` folder. However, the mp4-file that is saved there has always just a size of 262 byte and the "file contains no playable steams". So it seems it is a 'video' but made up of 0 frames? I don't understand what the problem is and how to debug from here.

Answer (score 3):

It was actually a bug that is fixed [here](https://github.com/openai/gym/pull/2139/commits/5c94ebabded3af1929033b72cba1c00e87c84dcf)

Answer (score 2):

Please ensure you have [FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) first.

```
brew install ffmpeg
```

One way is to run the code in an `Xvfd` virtual display.

The reason for this is video recording, which is done by taking screenshots of the window drawn by the environment. Some of the environments use `OpenGL` to draw its picture, so the graphical mode with `OpenGL` needs to be present.

This could be a problem for a virtual machine in the cloud, which physically doesn't have a monitor and graphical interface running. To overcome this, there is a special "virtual" graphical display, called `Xvfb` (`X11 virtual framebuffer`), which basically starts a virtual graphical display on the server and forces the program to draw inside it.

To start your program in the `Xvfb` environment, you need to have it installed on your machine (this usually requires installing the xvfb package).

Some resources to download and set it up:

[Link 1](https://techdocs.broadcom.com/us/en/ca-enterprise-software/it-operations-management/capacity-management/2-9-4/installing/capacity-command-center/post-installation-tasks/install-and-configure-xserver-virtual-frame-buffer-xvfb.html).

[Link 2](https://docs.oracle.com/health-sciences/empirica-signal-90/ESIIU/index.htm?toc.htm?224173.htm).

Then run `xvfd-run` with the python file and the video should be saved to the directory you specified:

```
xvfb-run -s "-screen 0 640x480x24" python cartpole_monitor.py
```

There are other ways such as running the code in an X11 session with the `OpenGL extension(GLX)` or using `X11` forwarding in an `SSH` connection.